# Status of linux process when core dumping

Tags: linux, process, coredump

Let's say I have a process which will generate a huge core file if it crashes somehow (e.g mysql). I want to know what's the status of the process when it core dumping. Is it as before or changing to zombie?

My real life problem is like this:
I have a monitor to check the status of a process. Once it realizes the process crashes(by monitoring the status of the process), it will do something. I want to make sure the monitor do something only after core dumping finished. That's why I want to know the process status when core dumping.

Comment: Would it really matter, as normally when the core has been dumped the process is terminated?

Comment: What would the monitor do? Is it starting the process with `fork`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Let's say if the core dump takes 10 mins and it changes its status to some bad status while doing this. Then my monitor may think the process is crashed and begin to tar the core file.

Comment: It's easy: If the status changes to "doing core-dump" (I don't know if that's a real status), then you continue to monitor the process, and when it is terminated you know the core-dump is finished.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think so. I wrote it with python and make use of psutil to create a process. I think it make use of fork. The monitor is a thread which make use of some lib in psutil to check the status of a process.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's exactly what I want to know. What's the status when process core dumping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your monitor is starting the processes with `fork` it should able to get `SIGCHLD` signals then call [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html). AFAIK `waitpid` will tell you when the `core` dumping has finished (and won't return successfully before that)

Read also [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html)

Perhaps using [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities on the directory containing the `core` dump might help.

And [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) might be relevant too (I don't know the details)

BTW, while core dumping, I believe that the process status (as reported thru [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) in 3<sup>rd</sup> field of `/proc/$PID/stat`) is

> ```
>        D  Waiting in uninterruptible disk sleep
> ```

So if you are concerned about long `core` dump time you could for example loop every half-second to `fopen` then `fscanf` then `fclose` that `/proc/$PID/stat` pseudo-file till the status is no more `D`

At last, *core dumps* are usually quick (unless you run on a supercomputer with a terabyte of RAM) these days (on Linux with a good file system like Ext4 or BTRFS), because I believe that (if you have sufficient RAM) the core dump file stays in the [page cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). Core dumps lasting half an hour were common in the previous century on supercomputers (Cray) of that time.

Of course you could also [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) the `core` file.

See also http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't explain the problem well. The monitor does not fork the process. It is just a thread there to check the status of the process I interested in(But this thread belong to the parent process of the process).

Comment: Looks like you might be interested in *systemd* (but I don't know the details)